# MySQL Error Code 3815 while trying to make a check constraint

Tags: mysql, constraints, check-constraints

Here is the table I am trying to make a constraint for:

```
create table All_Events(
event_id int not null auto_increment,
event_name varchar(50),
event_type int,
event_catagory int,
other_text varchar(20),
event_description varchar(200),
start_time time,
end_time time,
event_date date,
address varchar(100),
lat decimal(10,6),
lng decimal(10,6),
contact_phone varchar(10),
contact_email varchar(50),
creator_id varchar(10),
uni_name varchar(50),
rso_name varchar(50),
primary key(event_id),
foreign key (creator_id) references Users(uid),
foreign key (uni_name) references Universities(uni_name)
);
```

The goal of the constraint is to make sure that events on the same day and at the same location do not have time overlaps. This is what I have so far:

```
alter table All_Events add constraint timeChecker
    check ((
        select count(*) from All_Events A, All_Events B where A.event_date = B.event_date and A.address = B.address and (A.start_time > B.start_time and A.start_time < B.end_time) or (A.end_time > B.start_time and A.end_time < B.end_time)
    )=0);
```

The problem is when trying to add the constraint I get "Error Code 3815: An expression of a check constraint 'timeChecker' contains disallowed function" but no context as to what is disallowed. Any insight or help to get this constraint working would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html explains:

> Subqueries are not permitted.

I suggest you read the page I linked to in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

`DDL` is `static` not dynamic, therefore, you can't put queries inside the check.

If you want to make a restriction like that, you can use triggers, or pass the responsibility to the code behind.